# Swift - Array filter and then update the main array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray

```
let cities = [{ "name" : "SF", "id" : 4, "population" : 10, favorite: false},  { "name" : "NY", "id" : 5, "population" : 20, favorite: false}, { "name" : "DC", "id" : 6, "population" : 30, favorite: false}
```

I have an array and and lets say if a user applies a filter based on the population i can filter the array by using *filter* method, but it gives me an other array with filtered data. In filtered array user can favorite the city and when user removes the filter i need to show the full list of cities with the favorite indicator. Problem is filtered array is a separate array and the full array doesn't know if a property was changed on the filtered array. Is there any easier way handle all this? Can i filter the main array instead of creating another one?

Comment: Are the things in your array classes or structs?

Comment: @Paulw11 Structs but it can be changed if needed

Comment: Just use classes instead of structs. classes are passed by reference.

Comment: If you make them classes then they are reference objects and therefore mutable; There will only be one object referenced by both arrays, so updating the `favorite` property will show in both arrays, otherwise you need to update your underlying data model and refresh the unfiltered array from that

Comment: Thats a good idea, i can try it.

Comment: If you make favorite in the filtered array then also update the object in the main array so the favourite unfavorite change applies in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Create struct of JSON**

```
struct City {
    var name : String = ""
    var id : Int = 0
    var population : Int = 0
    var favorite : Bool = false
}
```

This is the array of cities

```
var cities = [City(name: "SF", id: 4, population: 10, favorite: false),City(name: "NY", id: 5, population: 10, favorite: false),City(name: "DC", id: 6, population: 30, favorite: false)]
```

Than apply filter on cities based on population == 10

```
var filter = cities.filter({ $0.population == 10 })
```

After that make favorite one of them

```
Ex:- filter[1].favorite = true
```

and also update this city favorite in the main array

```
cities = cities.map { (city) -> City in
    var city = city
    if city.id == filter[1].id {
        city.favorite = true
    }
    return city
}
```